# How to extract a version number pattern from a string variable in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to extract something from a command output variable but it's not working.

I want to extract the release number from the output and compare it with what I am passing as a command line.

```yaml
---
 - name: Get the status of Symlink
   stat:
     path: /opt/tomcat/apps/myapp
   register: p

 - debug:
     msg: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target }}"

 - set_fact:
     rid: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target | regex_search('release_version') }}"
```

Output

```yaml
Get the status of Symlink...
Friday 15 May 2020  18:43:51 +0100 (0:00:01.382)       0:00:01.559 ************
  server1 ok
debug...
Friday 15 May 2020  18:43:52 +0100 (0:00:00.508)       0:00:02.068 ************
  server1 ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "/opt/apache/releases/Release5.0.1/myapp/webapp"
}
set_fact...
Friday 15 May 2020  18:43:52 +0100 (0:00:00.071)       0:00:02.139 ************
  server1 ok
```

From above output, I want to extract `5.0.1` and compare with what I passed it in `{{ release_version }}`.

Comment: This expression -- `'({{release_version}})'` -- is invalid. You never nest `{{...}}` markers; if you're already inside a Jinja template context (which you are) you just refer to variables by name. You're searching for the literal string `({{release_version}})` which is never going to match anything.

Comment: @larsks Ok but even if i remove the brackets, it's not giving me anything. Am i doing the right way? I just want to match the 2 values and if they are same just return true OR false because my further plays depends on that. Can you please guide?

Comment: First correct the problems with your `set_fact` task: the entire value of your `rid` fact needs to be inside one set of `{{...}}` markers.

Comment: @larsks yes sorry I tried that and updated the question. It worked fine. Right now the value coming from the output is /Release5.0.1 and what I am passing is 5.0.1. Is there a way to match it and make it boolean like if the value doesn't match then then do something

Comment: @larsks Hi Thanks for your inputs. I have made it working. :)

Comment: @larsks It is still not working properly. I will put another question with more specific details

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to extract a version number from a string in Ansible? ... I want to extract the release number from the output and compare it with what I am passing ...***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    p:
      stat:
        lnk_target: '/opt/apache/releases/Release5.0.1/myapp/webapp'
    release_version: '5.0.1'

  tasks:

  - name: Show version
    debug:
      msg: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target | regex_search('[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}') }}"

  - name: Are they the same?
    assert:
      that:
        - release_version == p.stat.lnk_target | regex_search('[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}')
      success_msg: "Yes!"
```

will result into the requested output.

**Summary**

The `pattern` in the [`regex_search` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_search_filter.html) needs to be adjusted in order to "*extract regex match from string*" and as shown in the [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_search_filter.html#examples).